# Collection to pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, laravel-query-builder

Is there any way to make the collection paginate? For some data I need pagination. otherwise, it will retrieve as the collection. I used the below code for pagination. Any other way to solve it ?

```
  public function makePaginate($items, $perPage = 1005, $page = null, $options = [])
    {
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
```

Comment: This is the way to go. 
Additionally, there is this spatie [package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros), that adds many useful macros.